css slideshow image some time flicker and and some time just a blank between slide
I have created a slideshow for my project homepage, but on occasion, the screen simply flashes white and then resumes the slideshow. Could you kindly provide any suggestions? I have been unable to locate a solution on this forum that addresses my issue. I am only utilizing CSS and HTML.


.fade-box {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(/images/v-1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: 5s;
  animation-name: animate;
  animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
  animation-play-state: running;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-duration: 33s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    background-image: url(/images/v-2.jpg);
  }
  20% {
    background-image: url(/images/v-3.jpg);
  }
  40% {
    background-image: url(/images/v-4.jpg);
  }
  60% {
    background-image: url(/images/v-5.jpg);
  }
  80% {
    background-image: url(/images/v-6.jpg);
  }
  100% {
    background-image: url(/images/v-7.jpg);
  }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="fade-box"></div>
</body>

</html>




The blank flashes could be due to the image being downloaded in the background, and once the image is downloaded its slide is visible. The first time the slider loads, it is probably downloading the image every time the slide changes. The next time the slideshow repeats, it may not show blank flashes as the images are already downloaded.

Different browsers treat background image animation differently. What browser and OS are you using?

You can have image element and add some sliding/fading animation through keyframes.

I'm using Google Chrome on a windows 11. It behaves the same way on smaller devices too

Do you want the images to fade in and out gradually or one to replace another instantaneously? (I ask because of different browsers doing different things with background animation)

I would like them  to fade in and out gradually

The problem stems from starting the animation before all the images are loaded.
Loading a background image doesn't start until it's needed so there is often a pause (a white flash) in the animation to begin with.
One way round that which keeps the same animation is to ensure the images are all loaded before starting the animation.
This snippet does this by loading the images each in img elements and testing for the onload event.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .fade-box {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
      background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1024/768);
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      transition: 5s;
      animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
      animation-play-state: running;
      animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
      animation-duration: 33s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    
    @keyframes animate {
      0% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/21/1024/768);
      }
      20% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/22/1024/768);
      }
      40% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/23/1024/768);
      }
      60% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/24/1024/768);
      }
      80% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/25/1024/768);
      }
      100% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/26/1024/768);
      }
    }
    
    .imgs {
      position: absolute;
      top: 100vh;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="fade-box"></div>
  <div class="imgs">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/21/1024/768">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/22/1024/768">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/23/1024/768">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/24/1024/768">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/25/1024/768">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/26/1024/768">
  </div>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      document.querySelector('.fade-box').style.display = 'block';
      document.querySelector('.fade-box').style.animationName = 'animate';
      document.querySelector('.imgs').style.display = 'none';
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>



This is a rather sledge-hammer way of doing it, and has the additional problem that an if an image takes a long time to load for example, there is a noticable pause in the animation, or even possibly load never completing.
As the method requires loading as img elements anyway, you could consider animating those rather than the backgrounds, each using the same keyframes, staggered on starting and going from opacity 0 to 1 and vv.
Doing this would have the added advantage that different browsers would give the same experience. Currently Edge/Chrome fade background images in and out in keyframes, while Firefox changes them instantly, so to get a fading effect cross-browser you'll have to change the way the images are shown anyway.

Thanks a bunch! At least you fixed the flashing problem. I can't find the option to accept your solution. I thought there would be one, but I'm grateful for your work. Thanks again!
